# breaking a string inside an array to a character in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

sorry for the weird title, I am having a hard time explaining it. What I want is to compare the characters in my string like this:

```
stringa = new string[3];

for (int x = 0; x < stringa.GetLength(0); x++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("String" + (x + 1) + ":");
    stringa[x] = Console.ReadLine();
}

for(int x = 0;x < stringa.GetLength(0);x++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(stringa[x]);
}
```

What I want is that now that I have stringa[x], I want to compare every character inside that string. Is there any way I can do that without using any temporary variables?

Comment: *I want to compare every character inside that string* Compare to what?

Comment: Based on the code you've posted you'll have an array of 3 strings. What do you want the comparison for?

Comment: What are you trying to compare it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a character within a string by indexing.  For instance:

```
string myString = "Test string";
Console.WriteLine(myString[0]);
```

Will write the character 'T'

In your case, you *could* put another for loop inside your second one and call `stringa[x][y]` to get the y'th character in `stringa[x]`, but it's more efficient to store `stringa[x]` in a local variable and index that, like so:

```
for(int x = 0;x < stringa.Length(0);x++)
{
    // Store stringa[x] so that we don't have to keep indexing stringa
    string stringx = stringa[x];
    for(int y = 0;y < stringx.Length(0);x++)
    {
        // Do some comparison on stringx[y]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each character of a string can be accessed by index, so where the following shows the 1st string:

```
Console.WriteLine(stringa[0]);
```

This code shows the 1st char from the 1st string:

```
Console.WriteLine(stringa[0][0]);
```

To determine the length of each individual string, for looping purposes, you can find the length of the specific string like:

```
stringa[x].Length
```